# Dart: Simultaneous http requests

Tags: dart, dart-http

Problem: Http.get requests in future functions are called one after the other.

```
//this should open 5 simultaneous http connections
for (var i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
  getImage('[image soure]', i);
}
```

I've divided the method's code into several parts to better convey the problem.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void getImage(final String img, final int i) async {
  var blurHash = '';
  try {
    //PART: LOADING
    print('loading $img...');

    //PART: A
    var client = http.Client();

    var res = await client.get(img);

    print('$i: a');

    //PART: B
    var bbytes = res.bodyBytes;
    print('$i: b');

    //PART: C
    var l = bbytes.toList();
    print('$i: c');

    ...

    blurHash = '...';
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

What the console output should look like:

```
loading img.png
loading img.png
loading img.png
loading img.png
loading img.png
0: a
1: a
2: a
3: a
4: a
0: b
1: b
2: b
3: b
4: b
0: c
1: c
2: c
3: c
4: c
```

What the console output really look like:

```
loading img.png
loading img.png
loading img.png
loading img.png
loading img.png
0: a
0: b
0: c
1: a
1: b
1: c
2: a
2: b
2: c
3: a
3: b
3: c
4: a
4: b
4: c
```

This means that the loading part is executed simultaneously but it seems like the http.get requests in Part A are executed behind each other.

Comment: Is `getImage` = `generateBlurhash`? You're not `await`ing the `Future` method calls.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I updated the code.

Comment: I don't want to await the Future call. I want them to run simultaneously.

Comment: Then why is the actual output unexpected? The actual output is 4 `getImage` Futures simultaneously running while your expected would be one at a time.

Comment: From your expected output it seems you have a flawed understanding of `await`. `await` does not block across multiple instances of the same `Future`. It is simply different syntax for `.then`.

Comment: If I run ```for (var i= 0; i < 5; i++) { await getImage('[image soure]', i); }``` multiple instances of getImage are not executed on the same time. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you do that. Your code is already running simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

`await someFuture` (which as Christopher Moore explained in comments) is syntactic sugar for `return someFuture.then(...)`.  Execution from your function cannot yield unless it returns/awaits.

You can explicitly allow your functions to yield by sprinkling in some `await null` lines; that should allow your `getImage` calls to be interleaved in the way that you desire.  Note that doing so will not make things any faster; each Dart isolate executes Dart code in a single thread, so if you're not `await`ing an asynchronous operation whose underlying implementation involves another isolate or thread, you won't be saving any time overall.  Adding extra `await`s instead would introduce more context switching and make everything take a bit longer. (That still could be useful if your code needs to respond to other events while doing expensive operations, though.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think http.get is the problematic part. As you can see in the output the functions are loaded as i expected it until part a. Then the function basicly waited until the previous http request was finished. I've tested ```for (var i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
  await getImage('[image soure]', i);
}``` but I want the function to be executed simultaneously rather than 5 times after another.

Comment: @Velsem As I explained, a function can yield execution only when using `await` (or returning).  After the `http.Client.get()` call completes, `getImage` does not use any `await`s, so the rest of your function cannot be interrupted.  Again, you can't get true simultaneity since that code would be running in a single thread anyway.  If you want parallel execution, you will need to spawn separate Dart isolates.